# Approach to delete entities having references

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Customers can have a location and a location can be associated with multiple customers. And when user tries to delete a location which is associated with some customers, reference exception is raised. So, could anyone suggest which is best approach to handle this kind of situation like informing the user, etc. It's ASP.NET MVC web application.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to check if the users effectively CAN delete a location for a customer... if it can't don't display the delete icon/link. Of course you should do the check in the controller to be sure.

If the customer is related to a location that is shared to several other customers, the correct way of doing this is not remove the location itself but set to NULL the customer's property with the Location's ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In few other scenerio's, I just updated references with NULL. But in some cases, I have not-null fields for reference columns. So, I cannot do that. I was thinking if there is any other user friendly approach to do it. Otherwise the page gets directed to default error page.

Comment: @Sundeep, you can always check if the Customer really has related objects and if the can or cannot delete them. I use this approach to check if I can delete an entity (checking if the model is indeed from that user) and if the user can't delete it, just return a JSON object with the error message or redirect to a view to display the error situation.